# Replicate records base on Two Dates

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to change the below table

**Input**

```
Facility       From Date      To Date    DAYS
D             11-Sep-2017     13-Sep-17    3
C             26-Nov-2017     29-Nov-17    4
```

**Result**

```
Facility       From Date    DAYS
 D          11-Sep-2017     1
 D          12-Sep-2017     1
 D          13-Sep-2017     1
 C          26-Nov-2017     1
 C          27-Nov-2017     1
 C          28-Nov-2017     1
 C          29-Nov-2017     1
```

Comment: And are you having any difficulties doing so??

Comment: Yes, I have a dataset of 2000 records and the maximum record contains 70 Days in between. If I do it manually I will have to create over 30,000 records

Comment: That shouldn't cause any difficulties - whether it is 2 records or 2000, whether it is 1 day in between or 70 days, the code will be the same.  (I assume you have one loop which loops through the records and another loop, within the first one, which loops from start to end.  But what difficulty are you having??)

Comment: Where are your efforts?

Comment: I have a nested loop which loops 3 times on the first record and creates the record accordingly. However, jumping after creation of the records I tend to lose the index

Comment: Then post the code you are using and let us help you fix it.  It is **very** hard to help you if we can't see what is wrong.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks, I managed to get it working. I posted the answer. I used a sort where I didn't have to focus on the records with 1 day.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it working

```
Dim Marker As Integer
Marker = 2
While Marker > 1
    Marker = Range("H2").Value

For i = 1 To Marker - 1
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Next i

Range("H2:H" & Marker + 1).Value = 1
Range("F3:F" & Marker + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("H1:H2061"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Wend
```